# Map a image file through Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there any way to map a image file using a spring controller? In my spring application, I want store the images in the directory src/main/resources (i'm using maven) and access them with a method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="image/{theString}")
public ModelAndView image(@PathVariable String theString) {
    return new ModelAndView('what should be placed here?');
}
```

the string `theString` it's the image name (without extension). With this approach, I should be able to access my images this way:

```
/webapp/controller_mapping/image/image_name
```

Anyone can point a direction to do that?

Comment: You can return `HttpEntity<byte[]>` containing your image and needed headers. Image can be obtained by `getResourceAsStream` method of classloader http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov That should be an answer so you can get some Internet brownie points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return `HttpEntity<byte[]>`. [Construct](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html) new instance providing image byte array and necessary headers like content length and mime type then return it from your method. Image bytes can be obtained using classloader `getResourceAsStream` [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. It could use some cleaning up but it works. The ServiceException is just a simple base exception.

Good Luck!

```js
 package com.dhargis.example;

        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.IOException;

        import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

        import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
        import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;




      @Controller  
      @RequestMapping("/image")  
      public class ImageController {

     private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ImageController.class);
     
     private String filestore = "C:\\Users\\dhargis";
     
     //produces = "application/octet-stream"
     @RequestMapping(value = "/{filename:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public void get( @PathVariable String filename,
       HttpServletRequest request, 
       HttpServletResponse response) {

      log.info("Getting file " + filename);
      try {
       byte[] content = null;
       File store = new File(filestore);
       if( store.exists() ){
        File file = new File(store.getPath()+File.separator+filename);
        if( file.exists() ){
         content = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
        } else {
         throw new ServiceException("File does not exist");
        }
       } else {
        throw new ServiceException("Report store is required");
       }
       
       ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
       out.write(content);
             out.flush();
             out.close();
      } catch (ServiceException e) {
       log.error("Error on get", e);
      } catch (IOException e) {
       log.error("Error on get", e);
      }
      
     }

    }
```

```html
   

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```